# Storing unconfirmed email column on the sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm using Devise with Confirmable module enabled.

I realised that unconfirmed email column is only used when the user already has a confirmed email and wants to change it.

**I have the following issue:**

- The user "A" signed up with a email that belongs to user "B". The user "A" will never get success on confirm his account.
- After that, the user "B" try to sign up with your own email (already used by user "A" before). The user "B" can't sign up because your email is being used by someone else.

I think that on sign up page, the email should be stored in unconfirmed email column to avoid the  behavior above.

There is a workaround to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very interesting question. I think that the simplest way (but not sure that it is the best way) to prevent this problem is just to change email uniqueness validation and make it work only if email was confirmed.

To do this you should disallow `validatable` module in your User model and implement validations manually.

You can copy all default validations from here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb, but `validates_uniqueness_of`. Then implement your own email uniqueness validation:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   # do not include :validatable module here
   devise :confirmable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, ...  

   # your own validations
   ...
   validates_uniqueness_of :email, allow_blank: true, if: lambda { |u| u.email_changed? && u.confirmed? }
   ...
```

**Edited**:

My solution is not right. First of all, email can't be confirmed if it just changed. Even if my solution would work and allow user to register with existing unconfirmed email, when the user would try to confirm his email he would fail anyway.

**The right solution is:**

1) Add validation to prevent registration if email exists and confirmed.

2) Redefine `#confirme!` method to don't confirm email if it exists and confirmed

3) (not neсessary) Redefine `#after_confirmation` method to remove all other unconfirmed accounts with this email

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # do not include :validatable module here
  devise :confirmable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable  # , ...

  validate :confirmed_email_uniqueness

  scope :with_confirmed_email, -> { where.not(confirmed_at: nil) }
  scope :with_unconfirmed_email, -> { where(confirmed_at: nil) }

  def confirm!
    return false if confirmed_email_exists?  # or add validation error, or raise some exception
    super
  end

  private

  def confirmed_email_uniqueness
    errors.add(:email, "already exists") if email_changed? && confirmed_email_exists?
  end

  def confirmed_email_exists?
    User.with_confirmed_email.where(email: self.email).exists?
  end

  protected

  def after_confirmation
    User.with_unconfirmed_email.where(email: self.email).destroy_all
    super
  end

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I'm studying alternatives and I will accept your answer if applicable. Don't you think is it a important business rule thing?

Obviously isn't common situation but, in my point of view, Devise should care about this. 

What you think?

Comment: I agree with you and I was very surprised about this issue.